Excel formula for returning list of values that match criteria
Sheet 1:
       A            B            C          D           E
1 **Category**   **TOM**      **BOB**    **JIM**     **TIM** 
2 Product 1         1            1          1           0
3 Product 2         2            0          3           1
4 Product 3         0            2          2           2
5 Product 4         3            0          1           1
6 Product 5         2            3          0           0

RESULT REQUIRED:
Sheet 2:
Product 1
TOM
BOB
JIM
TIM

Sheet 3:
Product 2
TOM
JIM
TIM

Sheet 4:
Product 3
BOB
JIM
TIM

And so on. Basically, need 1 formula to run on the entire sheet 1 and automatically populate all the other sheets with names/values & filtered out only the names that have values that are >0.

Welcome. What formulas have you tried so far?

Formula will not populate data on a different sheet. You will need vba for that. Now if you want to put a formula on each sheet then that can be done(see below). But 1 formula to run on the entire sheet 1 will not work.
On each sheet, Put the desired product name in A1 and the following formula in A2:
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:Z1,INDEX(B:Z,MATCH(A1,A:A,0),0)>0))

And it will filter the names on the first row where the value on the row where the products match and spill them down the column.

